# Dynamically import packages with multiple files in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module

I am trying to dynamically import modules in python.
I need something like a plugin import system.

I use the following code for import of a module, and it works fine, as long as the entire code of the module is in the same file.

`caller.py` code:

```
PluginFolder = "./plugins"
MainModule = "__init__"
possibleplugins = os.listdir(PluginFolder)
for possible_plugin in possibleplugins:
    location = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PluginFolder, possible_plugin))
    if not os.path.isdir(location) or not MainModule + ".py" in os.listdir(location):
        continue
    info = imp.find_module(MainModule, [location])
    plugin = {"name": possible_plugin, "info": info}
```

After that, I use the load_module method to load the module:

```
module = imp.load_module(MainModule, *plugin["info"])
```

The structure of the directories is as follows:

```
Project/
  --plugins/
  ----plugin_1/
  -------__init__.py
  -------X.py
  caller.py
```

Everything works great when all the methods are in the same file (`__init__.py`).

When the method I use in `__init__.py` calls another method from another file (in the same package) than an error saying "No module named X"

the `__init__.py` code fails at the line:

```
import X
```

I also tried

```
import plugin_1.X
```

and other variations.

Just to make sure you guys understand- importing and using the module in a normal way (not dynamically) works fine.

What am I missing?
Is there another way to do this? Maybe use the `__import__` method, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `importlib`. It's `load_module` method does the job. You can put the importing code into `plugins/__init__.py` to do the following:

```
import importlib
import os
import logging

skip = set(("__init__.py",))

plugins = []

cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

for mod in glob.glob("*.py"):
    if mod in skip:
        continue
    try:
        mod = mod.replace(".py", "")
        plugin = importlib.import_module("." + mod, __name__)
        plugin.append(plugin)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warn("Failed to load %s: %s. Skipping", mod, e)

os.chdir(cwd)
```